# formvalidation.io - tooltips not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, formvalidation.io

I am trying to setup formvalidation with my rails app.  I can't figure out why error messages aren't being displayed in tooltips.  I went over the formvalidation documentation several times and it looks right.  I am having difficulty troubleshooting the problem.  I have `formValidation.min.js` and `bootstrap.min.js`(formValidation version) in vendor/assets/javascripts.  I have `formValidation.min.css` in vendor/assets/stylesheets.

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require formValidation.min.js
//= require bootstrap.min.js
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require bootstrap-select.min
//= require bootstrap-typeahead-rails
//= require turbolinks
//= require fancybox
//= require_tree .

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#custom-tag').formValidation({
    framework: 'bootstrap',
    err: {
      container: 'tooltip'
    },
    icon: {               
      valid: null,
      invalid: null,
      validating: null
    },
    fields: {
      tag: {
        validators: {
          stringLength: {
            min: 3,
            max: 10,
            message: 'Must be between 3 and 10'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

**application.css.scss**

```
/*
 *= require bootstrap-select.min
 *= require bootstrap-typeahead-rails
 *= require formValidation.min.css
 *= require fancybox
 */
```

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.0.beta1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'font-awesome-sass'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-typeahead-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.3.0'
gem 'fancybox2-rails', '~> 0.2.8'
```

Comment: is `custom-tag` the id of the form you are validating against?

Comment: @SeanHuber yes it is